# How to get a vector from a list in list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a text file that contains following data.

2010/07/07,1111,1,2,3

2010/07/08,1111,4,5,6

2010/07/09,1111,7,8,9

I put this into an array as a list in list format.
(I feel really stupid to do in this way but I could not think of any other way. I'd like to know smarter way to do this.)

```
file = open('some.csv','rU')
array = []
for line in file:
    #print line
    array.append(line)

e = []
for i in array:
    a =  i.split(',')
    b = time.strptime(a[0],"%Y/%m/%d")
    c = a[1]
    d = np.array(a[2:], dtype='i')
    e.append([b,c,d])
```

Then I'd like to extract that vector that has elements [2,5,8] so I did

```
f = e[:][2][1]
```

but this returns

```
'1111'
```

I don't understand since e[0][2][2] returns 2.

Can someone explain why it does not work when I use [:]?

Comment: What do you think `e[:]` does?

Comment: `e[:]` creates a shallow copy of your list, `[2]` gets the third sublist and `[1]` gets the second subelement of that sublist, if you look at `e` I think you will see you don't have what you think you do, you would need `print([arr[1] for arr in zip(*e)[2]])` to get what you wanted from the list

Comment: Or use vstack to create a single array, `print(np.vstack(zip(*e)[2])[:,1]`

Comment: I'm confused. If each line has 5 comma separated items, where is element 8 and what does this have to do with `e[:][2][1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `e[:][2][1]` returns element `1` of the element `2` of `e[:]`, where `e[:]` is a shallow copy of `e`.

To express the idea of "element `1` of element `2` of each row of `e`", you should use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
f = [x[2][1] for x in e]
```

---

Bonus: You can also define a class that supports indexing across the elements of an iterable.

```
class Comprehension(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._iterable)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return Comprehension(getattr(elt, name) for elt in self._iterable)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return Comprehension(elt[item] for elt in self._iterable)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Comprehension(elt(*args, **kwargs) for elt in self._iterable)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
f = list(Comprehension(e)[2][1])
```

This class also supports attribute lookup and function calls.

```
>>> list(Comprehension(range(10)).bit_length())
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are already using `numpy`. You can use `numpy.loadtxt` to load the array from file.

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from time import strptime

file_data = """\
2010/07/07,1111,1,2,3
2010/07/08,1111,4,5,6
2010/07/09,1111,7,8,9
"""

# create the date type that describes your data -> (label, type, additional_data)
dtype = [
    ("date", object), # store the time_struct as a python object
    ("string", bytes, 4), # need 4 bytes to store your string (if py2 use str rather than bytes)
    ("data", int, (3,)) # an array of 3 ints refered to by the label `data'
]

# describe how to convert the date string into the right object
converters = {0: lambda bytes_: strptime(bytes_.decode(), "%Y/%m/%d")}

arr = np.loadtxt(StringIO(file_data), delimiter=",", dtype=dtype, converters=converters)

# accessing the array
print(arr[0][1]) # plain int indexing -- 0th row, 1st element
print(arr[0]) # all of first row
print(arr["date"]) # get dates of all rows
print(arr[0]["date"]) # get date of first row
print(arr["date"][0]) # get dates of all rows then get the 0th element
print(arr[2]["date"].tm_mday) # get the day of the month of the last row (9)
print(arr["data"].sum(axis=1)) # sum the data of each row ([6, 15, 24])
```

Comment: This is helpful but it doesn't answer the question of how to access a given "column" of the data after creating the row array.  I think it would be something like `arr[:,2,1]`.